# Is it possible to allow different thread both read to and write from the same collection?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following wrapper:

```
public UserContianer{

    private List<User> users;


    public void add(User u){
         users.add(u)
    }

    public void update(User u){
        if(users.contains(u))
             //updating with the new value u
    }

    public User get(int index){
        return users.get(index);
    }
}
```

I need to allow multiple thread to read from and write the container simultaneously such that

- if read and written element of the list are different- that should be ok
- if read and written element of the list are the same then

  - if there's already a thread updating the element all read operation should be blocked untill the write operation's finished
  - if there's a thread reading some element, all write operations should be blocked until the reading's finished

First of all, are such requirements even make sense? I'm new to multithreading and maybe that's actualy not what I wanted.

Secondly, is it possible to implement the requirements in Java?

Comment: If you're new to multithreading, you should just wrap the collection with a lock and leave it at that. The read and write operations should be very quick and the additional cost of the more complex locking to allow the extra concurrency will be very unlikely to be justified by the microscopic increase in concurrency.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you, got it. So, the second question is if such requirements could make son=me sense in pratice?

Comment: They can in cases where the read and write operations are complex, for example, if the write requires looking at the current state, doing some computations, and then updating the state. It can also make sense where you have complex reads and writes are very rare.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to wrap your existing List in a synchronized version with [`Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)). This allows thread-safe use of the List, if all access is through the synchronized wrapper.

Note that the elements in the List are *references*. If you want to lock the List while you're making changes to objects, you'll need to synchronize at a higher level. One way to do this is to mark methods as `synchronized`.

```
 public synchronized void update(User u) { ... }
```